# Burninate code-review tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

The [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) beta site is now almost 2 years online. Code Review questions can and should be asked there.

But there still exist a [code-review](/questions/tagged/code-review) tag on Stack Overflow. Shouldn't that tag be burninated?

The about text of that tag says

> ... On Stack Overflow, questions to review code are generally off-topic. It is recommended to post such questions on the Code Review sister site.

Comment: It doesn't appear this tag is even being used for the intended "code review" purposes anyways. I can't wrap my head around why [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13561282) is tagged with it...

Comment: @animuson: gerrit is a code-review application.

Comment: Can we make it so that any question tagged with `code-review` is automatically migrated to the Code Review site?

Comment: Existence of this tag [is suggesting new users that code-review is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946720/how-to-optimize-this-program-in-python#comment31459017_20946720). IMHO it should be burninated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can completely eliminate the tag.  Like [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) and similar tags that now have their own site, there are older questions in [code-review](/questions/tagged/code-review) that *were* once on-topic on Stack Overflow, but will never be migrated to the new site.

Comment: How about deprecating the tag?

Comment: @juergend I don't think we have a way to officially deprecate a tag, other than recommending that in the tag wiki that it no longer be used.

Comment: The idea of a 'deprecation' feature came up as a consequence to the homework tag cleanup - it would block a tag from being used but not require its removal on existing questions prior to saving them after an edit. I don't think it's been officially proposed, but this now provides two good examples of where it would be useful. I might write a feature request for it later if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: @TimPost, it has been [officially proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151920/179419). You even answered it :-).

Comment: @Ben I guess after a while .. all your meta answers just sort of run together. Doh!